# TensorFlow example, MemoryError while run text_classification_character_cnn.py

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification_character_cnn.py for learning, but I get an error message:

File "C:\Users\natlun\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 72, in load_csv_without_header
    data = np.array(data)

MemoryError

I use CPU installation of TensorFlow and Python 3.5. Any ideas how to solve the problem?? Other scripts using a csv-file for input work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. And after many hours of reading and googling (and seeing your unanswered question), and just comparing the example with other examples that do run, I noticed that

```
dbpedia = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset(
  'dbpedia', test_with_fake_data=FLAGS.test_with_fake_data, size='large')
```

should just be

```
dbpedia = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset(
  'dbpedia', test_with_fake_data=FLAGS.test_with_fake_data)
```

Based off of what I've read about numpy, I'd bet the "size='large'" parameter causes an over allocation to a numpy array (which throws the memory error).

Or, when you don't set that parameter perhaps the input data is truncated.

Or some other thing. Anyway, I hope this helps others attempting to run this useful example!

**--- Update ---**

Without "size='large'" the load_dataset functions appears to create smaller training and test data sets (like 1/1000 the size).

After playing around with the example I realized I could manually load and use the whole data set without getting the memory error (assume it is saving the whole data set as it appears).

```
# Prepare training and testing data

##This was the provided method for setting up the data.
# dbpedia = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset(
#     'dbpedia', test_with_fake_data=FLAGS.test_with_fake_data)
# x_trainz = pandas.DataFrame(dbpedia.train.data)[1]
# y_trainz = pandas.Series(dbpedia.train.target)
# x_testz = pandas.DataFrame(dbpedia.test.data)[1]
# y_testz = pandas.Series(dbpedia.test.target)

##And this is my replacement.
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []

with open("dbpedia_data/dbpedia_csv/train.csv", encoding='utf-8') as filex:
    reader = csv.reader(filex)
    for row in reader:
        x_train.append(row[2])
        y_train.append(int(row[0]))

with open("dbpedia_data/dbpedia_csv/test.csv", encoding='utf-8') as filex:
    reader = csv.reader(filex)
    for row in reader:
        x_test.append(row[2])
        y_test.append(int(row[0]))

x_train = pandas.Series(x_train)
y_train = pandas.Series(y_train)
x_test = pandas.Series(x_test)
y_test = pandas.Series(y_test)
```

The example seems to now be evaluating the whole training data set. But, the original code will probably need to be run once to get/put the data in the correct sub-folders. Also, even while evaluating the whole data set little memory is used (just a few hundred MB). Which, makes me think that the load_dataset function is broken in some way.